# Outlook Web Access - Hide conflicts folder

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

Is it possible to hide the Conflicts folder for Outlook Web Access?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Outlook Web Access Administration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4bbe7065-a04e-43ca-8220-859212411e10&displaylang=en) to configure OWA settings for the front end UI and/or back end.

I know you can configure whether all or specific public folders are available to end users but I am not 100% if the conflicts folder is included in this.